# Cannot clear "attributedText" property from UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

The title basically spells it out...I have a text field. When it's first responder, I want to use an attributed string to hilight all the text, in order to indicate to the user that anything they type will clear it. When it resigns first responder, I want to remove the hi-light and display plain text. Here's what I have:

```
func toggleHilight() {
    self.hilighting = !self.hilighting // This property is initialized to false

    if (self.hilighting) {
        self.inputURLField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.inputURLField.text, attributes: [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()])
    } else {
        self.inputURLField.text = BrowserNavManager.sharedInstance.currentURL.absoluteString
    }
}
```

According to Apple's docs, setting the "attributedText" property will clear the regular "text" property, and vice-versa:

`text`

> ...In iOS 6 and later, assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the attributedText property with the same text, albeit without any inherent style attributes...

`attributedText`

> ...Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the text property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information...

But for me, this is simply not the case. In fact, even explicitly setting "attributedText" to nil does...nothing. It still logs the same (i.e. NOT nil), and still shows the hi-lighted (attributed) text. I've also tried calling `setNeedsDisplay()`, which had no effect.

What the heck am I missing here? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved...I found a way to trigger the system hi-lighting (which is what I was trying to ape anyway) by setting the "selectedTextRange" property on the text field.